# Failed to swap BEP20 > BNB, WalletExecuteDelegateError

Tags: 0x

I try to use `0x Swap rest API` to swap a token.
buyToken=0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82
sellToken=0x07515f6d56879040b02c4d355df62ec5aede4c7e

But i got `WalletExecuteDelegateCallFailedError`, what happened?

Am i missing something?

The allowance is set to maximum and the balance is sufficient, tried with 1inch api and it works properly, what does that error means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x API doesn't currently support fee-on-transfer tokens, which `0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82` appears to be.

Comment: aaahhh, i see, that's explain everything :D

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the available balance or allowance set correctly to the 0x Exchange contracts.

Comment: The allowance is set to maximum and the balance is sufficient, tried with 1inch api and it works properly, that's why the url above shows different message now